# When two users try to send data to a printer

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I have printer server I all user that send print request to this server so I want to know the source of each request that comes to my server and by the way my server OS is Microsoft Windows 7.
For example I want to add computer ip in first of all printed paper to specify the user computer.
How can I do this? is there any kind of client application for printing that can solve my problem ?

Comment: What OS and version are you on? On Windows 8, for example (and most likely other versions of Windows as well), you should be able to do this by setting the printer to use a **separator page**.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling my server OS is windows 7

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  would you please explain more I want to find application that when ever user send a print request the ip of this user goes under his page for example or some how I can recognize that user computer

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include additional information. The question itself should be the authoritative source of all information needed to answer it. (Comments are meant to be ephemeral.) Also, besides the fact that Windows 7 isn't really a server OS, that's only half of the equation. If the clients are running Windows too, and you trust the clients, you may want to look into just setting up the clients to print **separator pages**. Not that I really see what you think you'll gain here, but...

Comment: If your primary aim is to find a software tool, then **this is off topic here** because software recommendation questions are off topic. We can help you solve your problem, which may possibly involve suggesting third-party software, but the focus of your question needs to be on the problem, not on seeking software to solve it.

Comment: Print management software will let you track what your users print. As @Michael explained, we cannot give recommendations here, but try a web search for "Printer Management Software"